# How to read a specific element's value from json using Python?

Tags: python, json

I have the below sample json file and I would like to get the value of `ipAddress` using python.

```
{
  "hostId" : "65cb096f-7adb-4197-0c61-b0a1a67236d4",
  "ipAddress" : "10.2.1.354",
  "hostname" : "localhost",
  "rackId" : "/default",
  "hostUrl" : "http://localhost:7180/cmf/hostRedirect/65cb096f-7adb-4197-0c61-b0a1a67236d4",
}
```

I can use grep tool in shellscript to do this but no sure how to do it in Python.  Is there any specific tool in python like grep, awk or sed that shell does? My output should be `10.2.1.354`.

Comment: `import json; json.loads(data)['ipAddress']` easy stuff. Try searching first before asking

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
>>> import json
>>> f = open('file.json', 'r')
>>> obj = json.load(f)
>>> obj['ipAddress']
u'10.2.1.354'
```

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Don't waste your time answering such obvious duplicate questions please

Comment: @3kt, I have added a print statement to print 'obj'. Thanks for the help